# Add a new line in file?

Tags: ruby

I want to add a new line after a string is inserted.

My current code looks like this:

```
  File.open(filename, 'a') do |file|
    file.write @string
  end
```

How could I add a new line after the string is inserted?

Answer (score 198, accepted):

Use [IO#puts](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/IO.html#method-i-puts).

```
file.puts @string
```

Answer (score 53):

`file.write "\n"`

Comment: Check that you have "\n" and not '\n'

Comment: This really needs to be emphasized. I made the '\n' mistake and the consuming program couldn't recognize the new line or remove it via string or regex methods. Not fun.

Answer (score 2):

In case if you can't use [IO#puts](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/IO.html#method-i-puts):

```rb
file.write "text#{$/}"
```

where `$/` represents OS-dependent new line separator.